# Cant enter imaginary numbers in SageMathCloud

Tags: sage

I am trying to simply enter the character "i" into SageMathCloud so that I can construct imaginary numbers, this is my syntax:

```
ran40 = matrix(QQ,2,2,[[2*i,-2],[3,4]])
show(ran40)
```

I am constructing a matrix so that I can compute the reduced-row echelon form. The first element that is 2*i just needs to be **2i** but I keeping getting syntax errors, how do I enter *i* for an imaginary number into SageMathCloud? I cannot find an example anywhere on the internet, if anyone knows this syntax please do inform me.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you decided what the ring is, and that ring doesn't have any imaginaries.

```
matrix(QQ,2,2,[[2*i,-2],[3,4]])
```

`QQ` is the rationals (the fraction field of `ZZ`, if you like).

Is [this](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=miysvr) what you want?  It will make things in the "symbolic ring" which can be slow...

```
M = matrix(2,2,[[2*i,-2],[3,4]])
show(M)
show(M.echelon_form())
show(M.rref())
```

Comment: See also the complementary answer at http://ask.sagemath.org/question/32665/how-do-i-enter-an-imaginary-number-into-a-matrix/